# Install phpmyadmin, and what is the default username and password

Tags: mysql, php

What is the default username and password for PHPMyAdmin?  Also, did I install this right if I extracted the zip file from the download, and then plopped the folder onto my PHP compatible web server?  Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the default user and documentroot of apache:
/var/www/htdocs user apache

What steps do i need to install phpmyadmin ?

1. [Download the source file](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php)
2. Untar or Unzip the file `tar -zxvf phpMyAdmin-3.3.7-english.tar.gz`
3. To simplify changed the ugly directory name to phpmyadmin `mv phpMyAdmin-3.3.7-english phpmyadmin`
4. Change the owner recursively to all files within it `chown -R apache.apache phpmyadmin`
5. Move the folder to our DocumentRoot directory `mv phpmyadmin /var/www/htdocs/`

**Congratulation you have completed the first stage!**

---

What steps do i need to configure the installed phpmyadmin ?

1. Enter the phpmyadmin directory `cd /var/www/htdocs/phpmyadmin`
2. Rename the configuration file `mv config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php`
3. Open the configuration file on your preferable editor `vi config.inc.php`
4. Edit the line `$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '';` with some random password or w/e you want
5. Now you can login with your MySQL user or with your root MySQL user.

**Congratulation you have completed the last stage!**

---

**BONUS STAGE:** To create a database within your MySQL server:

```
mysql -uroot -p
create database DATABASE_NAME_HERE;
grant all privileges on DATABASE_NAME_HERE.* to 'USERNAME_YOU_WANT_TO_USE_HERE'@'%' identified by 'PASSWORD_FOR_THIS_USERNAME_HERE';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Congratulation you have cleared it all!**

Comment: Hey thanks sooo much for the amazingly helpful response! :)

Is there any reason why when I type `echo $PATH` that I get an output of `/usr/local/mysql/bin:??` and therefore I have to type `/bin/ls` to use that command, and `chown` doesn't come up at all..

Comment: try `sudo command`, for example `sudo ls /usr/local/mysql/bin` or login from your current user to root with full rights with the command `su -` note that you do need the space and the minus after `su`.

Comment: Hmm, I get `sudo` and `su -` command not found! :( Ahhh!  Almost every command isn't found

Comment: Forgot to ask you the basic what operational system are you in ? how did u login to it (remote or physical access) ?

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 (snow leopard) I'm logged into my normal account, but as far as I know, it has "superuser" or at least admin properties, and these commands used to work, I guess before I started playing around with MySQL and PHP.  So it's physical access.  I want to get this to my remote server eventually, but I'd like to get it working here first.

Comment: I'm sorry im not much into Mac so i can't really help you much with it but see this http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528 i know some stuff is pretty much the same but some are different so it would be better if you start a new question asking about how do you proper login as root or normal user on Mac and how to have the path enviorment to work instead of having to use the full path of applications.